# The difference between GCC `-symbolic` and LD `-Bsymbolic` options

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, compiler-flags, linker-flags

I see `-symbolic` options in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html.
I also see `-Bsymbolic` option in https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html.

Are they the same thing? What's their difference?